# How To Bind a textbox with ListBox's ScrollBar?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I have  a listbox with some items in it. I have a textbox too. What I want is to make a XAML only code using Triggers that would bind the Textbox when the Up and down arrows of the Listbox are clicked.

The Listbox used is the one in WPF (VS 2008) .

I have the listbox XAML like this .

```
<ListBox Margin="127.181,82.882,101,0" Name="listBox1" Height="21.435" VerticalAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="listBox1_ScrollChanged">
            <ListBoxItem Content="00"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="01"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="02"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="03"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="04"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="05"/>
        </ListBox>
```

So the listbox will have all the items in it. when the user presses the default scrollbar's down arrow , the value should also get updated in the Textbox.

Remember : We are not using **SelectedItem** Property

Comment: You cannot create event handlers in XAML. What is the reason you do not want to use code behind?

Comment: <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=listBox1, Path=SelectedValue}"/>

Comment: And why are you not using the `SelectedItem` property?